# Problem with debbuging (Reason: Failed to connect to device. Please check power and cabling to target.)

Tags: debugging, upload, ide, connection, stm32

I am using Nucleo-F103RB board. I have some simple code with one LED, it is compiled and runs okay on this board, so I am trying to test debugging as an exercise for me, but It doest't work at all

[image]

The CubeIDE thinks that my devboard is not connected, but it IS connected (view from STM32 ST-Link Utility):

[image]

ST-Link is updated (view from STM32 ST-Link Utility again):

[image]
SN from ST-Link Utility just rewrited to CubeIDE:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Ho to fix it?:c

UPDATE: after closing ST Link Utility and running Debug (F11) again, I have this right now:

[image]

Comment: Was ST-Link Utility open when you tried to debug on STM32CubeIDE? If so, try again after closing it.

Comment: My fault, I am sorry, I updated my first post - new error appears :c

Comment: Changing port number doesn't help too.